# Why is every fiber bundle over $S^1$ a mapping torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $f:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism. Consider the mapping torus $T_f=X\times I/(x,0)\sim (f(x),1)$ for $x\in X$. Then $X\to T_f\to S^1$ is a fiber bundle. I can see this.

> Every fiber bundle over $S^1$ is a mapping torus.

The above statement was said as a side note in the class. I tried to prove it but I'm quite new in this subject. I can't see any reference of the above statement on Google. Could you help?

Comment: You need to suppose that $f$ is a homeomorphism in order to get a fiber bundle. To prove the claim in question, I suggest using that fiber bundles over paracompact base spaces are (Hurewicz) fibrations. The intuition should be that the homeomorphism of the fiber is the monodromy obtained by traversing the base $S^1$ once.

Comment: @Thorgott I've never heard *monodromy* before. Wikipedia says that it's a map between groups not topological spaces. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @love_sodam In this context you're just supposed to think about transporting $x \in X$ around $S^1$ through all of the fibers to arrive at some $x' \in X$ in the original fiber: the induced map $x \mapsto x'$ is the *monodromy map*.

Comment: @KeeleyHoek Now it makes sense and intuitive. To make that definition in rigor, maybe I need to consider section of the given fiber bundle (am I right?). How can I define the map so that it really a map $x\mapsto x'$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite what was said in comments, I don't think that homotopic properties such as the homotopy extension property are going to be enough for us here, because we need to use that we have a fiber bundle (and not merely a fibration) in an essential way. Instead we'll use the fact that fiber bundles over a contractible base are trivial, proved perhaps on this site and e.g. this is Corollary 1.8 on p21 of [Hatcher's VBKT](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) (note that this is stated for vector bundles, but Hatcher remarks that the same proof for fiber bundles is fine).

If you're comfortable with the definition of a mapping torus and the basic construction below then I think you'd be safe saying that your question is a "trivial corollary" of this result about fiber bundles, but we're going to check everything very carefully.

---

To begin, let's think of $S^1$ as a quotient of $I = [0, 1]$ with $p : I \to S^1$ the quotient map and let $\pi : E \to S^1$ be a fiber bundle. Let $s_0 := p(0) \in S^1$ be a basepoint. We can then build the pullback bundle $p^* \pi : p^* E \to I$, and remember the associated bundle map $\widetilde{p} : p^* E \to E$ for later. Since $p^* \pi$ is a fiber bundle over a contractible base it is trivial, so let $\phi(t, x) : p^* E \to I \times F$ be a bundle isomorphism with $F := \pi^{-1}(s_0)$ a standard fiber. Then we can build the composite
$$
f : \pi^{-1}(s_0)
\xrightarrow{(\widetilde{p}\rvert_{(p^*\pi)^{-1}(0)})^{-1}} (p^* \pi)^{-1}(0)
\xrightarrow{\phi^{-1}} \{0\} \times F
\to \{1\}\times F
\xrightarrow{\phi} (p^* \pi)^{-1}(1)
\xrightarrow{\widetilde{p}} \pi^{-1}(s_0).
$$
Every map in this composite is a homeomorphism, so the entire composite is as well.

(The intuition is that this map: fixes an element $x$ of the fiber $F$ above $s_0 \in S^1$, chops the $S^1$ to get a fiber bundle over $I$, then "untwists" the bundle, pushes $x \in F$ from above $0 \in I$ in $I \times F$ to now sit above $1 \in I$---which essentially does nothing---then retwists the bundle and glues it back together. We return to a point in the fiber above $s_0$, but we need not have gotten $x$ back. Allowing $x \in F$ to vary in this procedure yields a homeomorphism $F \to F$.)

With the map $f : F \to F$ in hand, it remains to show that $\pi : E \to S^1$ is isomorphic to $M_f$. But this isn't so bad: by definition $M_f$ is a quotient of $I \times F$, so upon composing with the quotient map $q : I \times F \to M_f$ we have a bundle map $p^* E \xrightarrow{\phi} I \times F \xrightarrow{q} M_f$ which is a fiberwise isomorphism. This composite descends to a map $E \to M_f$ now over the same bases, hence an isomorphsim of fiber bundles, exactly when for all $y_1, y_2 \in p^* E$ such that $\widetilde{p}(y_1) = \widetilde{p}(y_2)$ we have $(q \circ \phi)(y_1) = (q \circ \phi)(y_2)$. (Don't forget the map $\widetilde{p} : p^* E \to E$ from the beginning, and if you like the condition we are checking is just the universal property of quotients.)

So, if we write $y_1 = (t_1, z_1) \in I \times E$ and $y_2 = (t_2, z_2)$ similarly then $\widetilde{p}(y_1) = \widetilde{p}(y_2)$ just says $z_1 = z_2$ and $p(t_1) = p(t_2)$. Obviously if $t_1 = t_2$ there is nothing to check, and the only way that $t_1 \not = t_2$ is if one is $0$ and the other is $1$. WLOG we can assume $t_1 = 0$ and $t_2 = 1$, in which case the elements $\phi(y_1) = \phi(0, z_1) = (0, x_1)$ and $\phi(y_2) = \phi(1, z_1) = (1, x_2)$ of $I \times F$ become equal in the quotient defining $M_f$ exactly when $f(x_1) = x_2$. But following the successive composites defining $f$ we trace out
$$
x_1 \mapsto (0, x_1) \mapsto \phi^{-1}(0, x_1) = y_1 \mapsto y_2 \mapsto \phi(y_2) = (1, x_2) \mapsto x_2,
$$
exactly as desired. This completes the proof.

Comment: While monodromy is the right picture intuitively speaking (as you also explain), my initial comment was not fully thought out, so I agree with your first paragraph. On second thought, I arrived at a solution pretty much agreeing with yours, but by the time I wanted to post a clarifying comment, you'd already beaten me to it with an entire elaborate answer (+1).